# Удалить элемент из списка

Tags: python, списки

Пытаюсь написать игру лото. Генерится карточка компьютера, карточка пользователя, и список из значений бочонков (90).

Далее в цикле сравнивается выпавший бочонок и список (карточка) пользователя или пк. Если есть совпадение, выводится: список (карточка), Bingo, <имя игрока>, номер выпавшего бочонка.

Как удалять уже выпавший бочонок из списков (карточек) игроков?

```
import itertools
import random

ListBochonok = []

for i in itertools.count(1):
    ListBochonok.append(i)

if i > 89:
    break

PcCard = random.sample(ListBochonok, 15)
print 'Карточка компьютера: ', PcCard

UserCard = random.sample(ListBochonok, 15)
print 'Карточка юзера: ', UserCard

print '-----------------------------------------------------'

for i in ListBochonok:
    randBoch = random.choice(ListBochonok)
    if randBoch in PcCard:
        print PcCard, 'Bingo Pc!', randBoch
    elif randBoch in UserCard:
        print UserCard, 'Bingo User!', randBoch
```

Выводит следующее:

Карточка компьютера:  [11, 68, 81, 77, 71, 31, 4, 85, 40, 45, 69, 78, 50, 48, 14]

Карточка юзера:  [16, 21, 14, 66, 80, 27, 74, 45, 20, 4, 70, 1, 54, 47, 29]

---

[16, 21, 14, 66, 80, 27, 74, 45, 20, 4, 70, 1, 54, 47, 29] Bingo User! 74
[11, 68, 81, 77, 71, 31, 4, 85, 40, 45, 69, 78, 50, 48, 14] Bingo Pc! 78
[16, 21, 14, 66, 80, 27, 74, 45, 20, 4, 70, 1, 54, 47, 29] Bingo User! 80
[11, 68, 81, 77, 71, 31, 4, 85, 40, 45, 69, 78, 50, 48, 14] Bingo Pc! 81
[11, 68, 81, 77, 71, 31, 4, 85, 40, 45, 69, 78, 50, 48, 14] Bingo Pc! 45

И так далее

Comment: Функция `remove()` позволяет удалить элемент из списка. В данном случае

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `remove()` позволяет удалить элемент из списка. В данном случае

```
UserCard.remove(randBoch)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не догадался в качестве аргумента дать randBoch